# Good documentation for gtkmm 2.4

Tags: c++, gnome, gtkmm

I've got a project that needs to use the gtkmm 2.4 API, however documentation for it has been really hard to find. The official gtkmm site has the following statement:

*Versions for the older gtkmm 2 API are also available.*

However I can't seem to find it anywhere. Anyone know of a place good place to get documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the following links:

[gtkmm: gtkmm Reference Manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/2.24/)

[Programming with gtkmm 2.24.2](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/2.24/)

[Gtk+ API Documentation (both, GTK+ 2 and 3](http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php)

Hth!

Comment: That is all for gtk3, the OP wants gtk2.4 documentation

Comment: The links are fixed now, pointing properly to GTKmm 2.24.2.  OTOH, the link to GTK+ points to both GTK+2 and GTK+3.

Comment: Second link is now dead (the 1st one was the one I was looking for, thanks)